# How to redirect on view page and hide the section-one and display the section-two without refresh the page in codeigniter?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, codeigniter

I have one view file including two sections.

```
<!--first section-->
<section class="section-one">
<!--some code here like form with submit button-->
<?php echo form_open('user_control/submit'); ?> 
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
</section>

<!--two section-->
<section class="section-two"><!--some success code here--></section>
.section-two{display:none;}//hide section-two
```

Section-one will display first when the user hit the URL then after filling the form the user will click the submit button.
It will call my controller called us `user_control/submit`.

I have added some code in the controller to submit data in the database which is working.

Now my issue is after submitting the data in the database how to redirect on same view page and hide the section-one and display the section-two without refresh the page?

I mean, I have to display the success text after submitting the data to the database in the same view page.

Would you help me out in this?

**Controller code here**

```
public function submit()
    {
        global $now;//current date
        $check_fields  = implode(",", $this->input->post('check-fields'));
            $data = array(
            'form_data'=> $check_fields,
            'form_created_date'=> $now
        );
        $this->db->insert('form_submit',$data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try submitting the form using ajax. After receiving ajax response hide first section and display second section. Below is the code which you can take hints from. Call ajax on button click. Also, change input type submit to input type button for doing ajax call.

```
 $.ajax({
                  url: "url of your method",
                  method: "POST", 
                  data : $('Your form name').serialize()
                  success: function(result) {
                          if(result) {
                               $(".section-one").hide();
                               $(".section-two").show();
                          } else {
                               //display error
                          }
                      }  
    });
```

Comment: I can do In core PHP I am talking about  Codeigniter. I mean I am getting a response from model to controller now I have to call the view file with a specific section.

Comment: in url place the url to you controller and then call your model within the controller and return some response from model to controller and then back to the view via the ajax call

Answer (score 0):

in url place the url to you controller and then call your model within the controller and return some response from model to controller and then back to the view via the ajax call

View:

```
var url = $('html').data('base-url')+'index.php/controller/ajax_some_method';

$.ajax({
   url: url,
   method: "POST", 
   data : {data_to_pass_accross}
   success: function(result) {
       if(result) {
             $(".section-one").hide();
              $(".section-two").show();
       } else {
           //display some error message
          console.log(response.message);
      }
  }  
});
```

Controller:

```
public function ajax_some_method(){

   //make model call 
   //get response back
   //send response back to view

   $data = ["success"=>true, "message"=>some message", "data"=>"what ever"];


  return die(json_encode($data));

}
```